# How to export 3D graphics as a .3ds file

Tags: export, graphics3d

I have made a graphic of  a 3D random walk:

```
rw = Accumulate[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {200, 3}]];

Graphics3D[
  {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[First @ rw], 
   PointSize[Large],Green, Point[Last @ rw], 
   Thickness[0.005], Red, Line[rw]}]
```

[image]

I tried to export it as a ".3ds" file (or ".obj"), but I get an error message.

[image]

Comment: The [documentation page of "3ds"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/3DS.html) says "Export to the 3DS format supports the following graphics primitives: GraphicsComplex, Cuboid, Cylinder, and Sphere." No `Line` among them...

Comment: OBJ can do it though, but not all viewers will show you the lines...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Tube` instead of `Line` and `Sphere` instead of `Point`.

```
A = Join[IdentityMatrix[3], -IdentityMatrix[3]]; 
rw = Accumulate[A[[RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 200]]]];
g = Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[First@rw, 0.2], Green, 
   Sphere[Last@rw, 0.2], Thickness[0.005], Red, Tube[rw, 0.1]}]
Export["a.3ds", g]
```